How to resolve circular foreign key constraints with NOT NULL in Hibernate
I'm dealing with a cyclic dependency issue between two entities (Store and Staff) in MySQL, which is causing issues when trying to save data using Hibernate ORM (version 6.6.0.Final, no Spring). The problem arises from foreign key and NOT NULL constraints in the database schema.
Database schema (MySQL)
Here are the relevant sections from my database dump:
store table:
CREATE TABLE `store` (
  `store_id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `manager_staff_id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `address_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`store_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_unique_manager` (`manager_staff_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_address_id` (`address_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_store_address` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `address` (`address_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_store_staff` FOREIGN KEY (`manager_staff_id`) REFERENCES `staff` (`staff_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

staff table:
CREATE TABLE `staff` (
  `staff_id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `address_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `store_id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `username` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40),
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`staff_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_store_id` (`store_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_address_id` (`address_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_staff_address` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `address` (`address_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_staff_store` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

Entity classes (Java)
Here are the Java entity classes for Store and Staff:
Store.java:
@Entity
@Table(schema = "movie", name = "store")
public class Store {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Short id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_staff_id", nullable = false)
    private Staff mainStaff;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", nullable = false)
    private Address address;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "mainStore")
    private List<Staff> staffList;

    // other fields...
}

Staff.java:
@Entity
@Table(schema = "movie", name = "staff")
public class Staff {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Short id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", nullable = false)
    private Address address;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", nullable = false)
    private Store mainStore;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "mainStaff")
    private List<Store> stores;

    // other fields...
}

Problem
When attempting to persist either Store or Staff, I encounter the following exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation:
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation:

It's clear that the cyclic foreign key constraint (store.manager_staff_id referencing staff.staff_id, and staff.store_id referencing store.store_id) creates a dependency loop, which prevents me from saving either entity first. I have tried:

Removing cascading and saving entities manually (doesn’t work).
Attempting to manage transaction boundaries to ensure one is persisted before the other, but the circular dependency causes the same issue.

Question
Is there a way to resolve this issue within the confines of using Hibernate (without Spring)? Can this be solved purely on the ORM level (Java side) without altering the database schema or constraints (since this is beyond my control)?
I'm looking for guidance on:

Correctly configuring cascading, if applicable.
Alternative ways to resolve the circular dependency while still adhering to the constraints imposed by the existing MySQL schema.


The solution I always prefer: avoid having such dependencies

@Stultuske If such a dependency already exists, can it be resolved in any way? There’s no possibility to change the data model. I don't have the necessary access or permissions for that.
Again, this is purely a theoretical question. If it's truly a dead-end situation, more radical solutions will be considered where possible.

How do you add those rows using SQL? You cant create a store without staff, you can't create staff without store.

@talexmovedtoCodidact I’m still learning, to be honest. Maybe that’s where the problem lies? I have a dump with an interesting database like this. The dump was fully restored without issues, and it even contains data. However, I can’t add anything new to it.
I noticed in the dump that before adding data, the following command was executed:

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE store DISABLE KEYS /;
INSERT INTO store VALUES (1,1,1,'2006-02-15 02:57:12'),(2,2,2,'2006-02-15 02:57:12');
/!40000 ALTER TABLE store ENABLE KEYS */;

Does this mean that without disabling keys, it’s impossible to add new data? And which keys are being referred to here? Any constraints, including NOT NULL?

It is possible to do it. My question is why someone decide to do it. Is it some programming puzzle or real project?

You can add new rows, you just need to reference existing rows.

@talexmovedtoCodidact Good question. Was this done intentionally or out of oversight? It's not exactly a puzzle, but more of a learning project aimed at gaining a deeper understanding of databases and working with ORM.

@Lexoid What exactly your goal here?

Ah, good idea! But adding entirely new and independent Store and Staff entries using Hibernate in this setup isn’t possible, as I understand? I thought cascading was to blame for everything here, but it seems like the situation is indeed unsolvable based on the logic of things...

@talexmovedtoCodidact My goal: to understand whether Hibernate can somehow resolve such situations? Or is it a dead-end from the start?

@Lexoid Kind of. You need some kickstart, but after you can manage. See my answer.

@talexmovedtoCodidact Thank you, my dear friend, now I’m really starting to understand! I thought so, but I had doubts. What if I just didn’t know something? These kinds of thoughts were troubling me.

You need to have at least one entity of each type for start.
When you need to create new one you reference existing one.
If you need new pair referencing each other:

Create them referencing existing entitys
Flush
Edit them to point to each other
Quit you job and never look back. It not worth it.


Okay. So, without that initial kickstart, as I understand, nothing will work? Meaning, I first need to have an entity, and then 'build' from it and somehow manage further? I can’t start from scratch, right?

Yes. But it isn't ORM problem. Same problem will be in pure SQL solution.

Now I fully understand everything. Indeed, with the reference entity, I was able to save it into the database. This seems to be the only solution, as otherwise, the situation cannot be resolved. I hope this will help other beginners to deal with this issue. Thank you very much!
